# Split XML based on member tag value

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have an xml which looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <staff>
        <firstname>John</firstname>
        <lastname>Player</lastname>
        <nickname>JP</nickname>
        <salary>1000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff>
        <firstname>Peter</firstname>
        <lastname>Shaw</lastname>
        <nickname>PS</nickname>
        <salary>2000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

I need to pick only when firstname is Peter i.e. my o/p should be:

```
        <staff>
            <firstname>Peter</firstname>
            <lastname>Shaw</lastname>
            <nickname>PS</nickname>
            <salary>2000</salary>
        </staff>
```

I am using XPath for it and the sample code looks like:

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("./company[staff/firstname = 'Peter']");

    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    System.out.println("Print  " + result);  //comes as com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList@ef0cdb
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result; 
    System.out.println("Size"+ nodes.getLength()); // comes as 0
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
    }
```

Kindly provide guidance

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath expression will pick a `<company>` that has *at least* one staff member with first name Peter in it.

What you actually want is to pick at `<staff>` level:

```
company/staff[firstname = 'Peter']
```